# Matched leaf route at location "/Gallary" does not have an element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am Trying to reach the `<Gallery/>` Component using a Menu button with React-Router Link
so the code is for the Menu

**Menu.jsx**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Menu({ menuOpen, setMenuOpen }) {
  return (
    <div className={"menu " + (menuOpen && "active")}>
      <ul>

        <li onClick={() => setMenuOpen(false)}>
          <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
        </li>
        <li onClick={() => setMenuOpen(false)}>
          <Link to="/Gallery">Gallery</Link>
        </li>
   </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**and the code for APP.jsx:**

```
import './App.scss';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Gallery from './components/Gallery/Gallery';
import Menu from './components/menu/Menu';
import Topbar from './components/topbar/Topbar';
import FooterComp from './components/Footer/FooterComp';

const App = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);


  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Topbar menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen} />
        <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/Gallery" elemtent={<Gallery />} />
        </Routes>

        <FooterComp />
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

When I click the button which is supposed to route to the `<Gallery/>` Component it routes to an empty component and this warning is displayed in the console

*Matched leaf route at location "/Gallery" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.*

I searched for this problem and only router-dom version related fixes are there and you can see I'm using the correct v6 props and components.

Comment: You've a typo in what *should* be the `element` prop, `elemtent={<Gallery />}` should be `element={<Gallery />}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. `element`

Change

`<Route path="/Gallery" elemtent={<Gallery />} />`

to

`<Route path="/Gallery" element={<Gallery />} />`

Comment: In the future, keep in mind that issues that are unreproducible or caused by typos should be flagged and closed as such as they are only helpful to the person making the typo and not very relevant/useful in general.